# Accessing 'this' in Javascript closure

Tags: javascript

This is more of a sanity check than anything else. I've found that when working with closures in Javascript I often use the following pattern to access the enclosing class from within the function:

```
MyClass.prototype.delayed_foo = function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.foo(); // Be nice if I could use 'this' here
    }, 1000);
};
```

Obviously this works just fine, and it's not even a big hassle to work with. There's just this little itch in the back of my brain that says 'You're making this too complicated, dummy!' Is this the commonly accepted pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the commonly accepted pattern with the exception that `that` is often used instead of `self`.

Comment: Good to know. I had just picked what felt familiar. :) (Big Python fan!)

Answer (score 4):

You can pull a sneaky using a binding function like this:

```
var Binder = function(fnc, obj) {
    return function() {
        fnc.apply(obj, arguments);
    };
};
```

and then changing your call to

```
MyClass.prototype.delayed_foo = function() {
    setTimeout(Binder(function(){
        this.foo("Lols");
    },this), 1000);
};
```

jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/6VaV6/

Comment: Well, that certainly is an amusing little trick, but reading through the code I feel like I'm back in C# again binding anonymous delegates! Probably not worth the performance overhead and extra code complexity just so I can call my class var "this". A+ for creativity, though!