# How should I name my javascript library functions so they are differentiable from plain old javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a custom UI builder in js. It uses an implementation of a factory to build elements. To make sure that it was obvious which functions were part of the library versus which were part of plain old javascript I used a naming convention of `function _FunctionName()`. However, I find it tedious to always be doing `Factory._FunctionName()`.

Should I just remove the naming convention (`function FunctionName()`)or stick to it?

Are there naming convention common / best practices with regards to making libraries like this?

edit:

```
var __PanelFactory = function () {
 //"private"
 var Panels = [];
 //exposed
 function _GetPanel(id) {
  //etc
 }
 return {
    _GetPanel: _GetPanel,
 };
};

var Factory = new __PanelFactory();
Factory. //this will show certain plain javascript functions 
         //like toString, constructor, hasOwnProperty, isPrototypeOf, etc...

//note that even jQuery can have the previous list used with something like
$(selector).

//So to differentiate I made sure my functions start with _
Factory._GetPanel(1);

//Should I just make it easy on myself and allow
Factory.GetPanel(1);

//Or is there value in leaving the naming convention in?
```

Comment: Why are you making your factory functions global, rather than scoping them to a specific namespace?  (for example, like how jQuery methods all live under `$` or `$.fn`.)

Comment: @KirkWoll - However, javascript still allows the basic `.toString`, `constructor`, etc. to any of those. How do you know they are naked functions?

Comment: @TravisJ: If they're scoped to a namespace, I think they'll already be differentiable.  I think you *have* to specify the namespace when you call them (?)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham - They must be accessed only after the factory has been initialized with `var Factory = new Factory()`.

Comment: @TravisJ: So, like `var factory = new Factory();` ... `factory.DoSomething();`?  Your question makes it look like you're talking about functions that aren't bound to instances of objects.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham - Sorry for a lack of context, let me edit with more of an example.

Comment: @KirkWoll - See edit for an example, clearly the functions are *not* global.

Comment: I admit I'm thrown by the naked, `Factory.` -- what is that intended to convey?  Regardless, I'm also confused by why you think `Factory._GetPanel(1);` would collide with anything.  It would only compete with members defined for `Factory`, which isn't much!  Why do you think you need to add any prefixes to distinguish it from anything else?

Comment: @KirkWoll - The `Factory.` was intended to show the stopping point for when exposed methods show up in an IntelliSense type environment. Mostly just to point out that at that point there could be a lot of calls that could be made starting with `Factory.` such as `Factory.toString()`, or `Factory.toHtml()` (which would be custom), or `Factory.constructor` (plain js), etc... As for why I thought I would need to add prefixes, I was just trying to be rigorous in making sure that what I am making is easy to use and to be easily distinguishable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a question already on SO that links to a good document on Javscript coding conventions (including naming):

- [javascript naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921133/javascript-naming-conventions)
- http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

The key bits you've asked about:

- Use namespaces (with inital-caps names).

This is somewhat optional, as `PanelFactory` won't collide with plain Javascript.  It might collide with other libraries if you are making a public API to be consumed by third parties, though:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
MyApp.__PanelFactory = function () { // ...
```

- Get rid of the underscores (`_`) before all function names.

You don't need the underscores, as people who have been working with JavaScript for a while know the default instance-scoped functions built into every object (`toString` etc):

```
MyApp.PanelFactory = function () {
  // ...
  function GetPanel(id) {
    //etc
  }
```

- Name object constructor functions with initial-caps names, but name global or namespace-scoped functions and instance-scoped functions with initial-lower-case names:

This is just a standard convention.  It doesn't help distinguish built-in functions, but as I said in the previous item, you don't need to.

```
MyApp.PanelFactory = function () {
  // ...
  function getPanel(id) {
    //etc
  }
```

- Name local variables with initial-lower-case names:

This will help you tell the difference between a namespace, an object constructor, and an instance of an object (where you would expect custom instance-scoped functions, commonly called "methods", to exist).

```
var factory = new MyApp.PanelFactory();
var panel = factory.getPanel();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some pretty common conventions in javascript.

### Constants

Usually in ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES

```
var MAX_COUNT = 100;
var BASE_URL = "http://example.com/api/";
```

### Variables

Usually in lowerCamelCase

```
var currentCount = 0;
var userName = "timrwood";
```

### Constructors

Usually in UpperCamelCase

```
function Factory(){}
var factory = new Factory();
```

### Methods

Usually in lowerCamelCase

```
Factory.prototype.getPanel = function(){};
var factory = new Factory();
var panel = factory.getPanel();
```

### Private Variables/Methods

Usually in _lowerCamelCaseWithAUnderscorePrefix;

```
Factory.prototype._fetchPanel = function(){};
Factory.prototype.getPanel = function() {
    return this._fetchPanel();
}
```

Comment: +1 for nice overview, but I have a remark. Although using `_` for private fields is sometimes used, there are actually semantically better ways of declaring private fields - as a variable in a closure.

Comment: Yeah, a variable in a closure is definitely safer, but sometimes you need to add something to the prototype to be referenced with `this`, and using an underscore is pretty good indicator that it is intended to be private.

Comment: @timrwood: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813119/accessing-this-in-javascript-closure