# Is there a functional purpose for setting a variable to 'this'?

Tags: javascript, this

As in, sometimes when I look at code by other people, they will go `var self = this;` or in jquery for example, go `var $self = $(this);`

is there a particular reason for doing so?

Comment: Yes, if you want to reference the value of `this` in another function (closure). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: Yes, whenever you wish to access properties of that object in a context where `this` will refer to, instead, another object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813119/accessing-this-in-javascript-closure

Comment: I have read through the entire thing. I'm just confused with this line 'That's why an easy solution is to simply create a new variable that also refers to that object.' In the example, are you essentially making it 'self.data = data;'? And if so, what is self? I thought the point of using 'this' was so that it would refer to whatever object called it

Comment: @slynthin: `self` has the same value as `this`, so yes, it will refer to a new instance of `MyConstructor`. But I also want to be able to refer to that object inside the event handler. I can't use `this` because `this` has a different value inside the event handler. So I'm keeping a reference to the value of the original `this` in a separate variable.

Answer (score 1):

It preserves the value of `this` for use in functions defined inside the current function.

```
// Contrived example
var myObject = {
    func: function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(bar, 1000);

        function bar () {
            alert(this); // `window`
            alert(self); // `myObject`
        }
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Answer (score 1):

By holding a reference to `this` in some context, you have the ability to access it in other contexts such as within member functions or `forEach` loops.

Consider the following example:

```
function ViewModel() {
   var self = this;

   self.linksArray = ["link1", "link2", "link3"];

   self.linksArray.forEach(function(link) {
       // this refers to the DOM window
       // and self refers to the parent context (ViewModel)
   });
};
```

Comment: so if you set a variable to this while this is in a particular context you can put the variable in another context (not the original) and the variable is still equal to the value of this in the original context?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you could set a variable to $(this) if you wish to use it in another function.

On practical example would be when doing an ajax call tied to an event on the page.  Using JQuery:

```
<script>

        $(document).on("click", ".mySelector", function () {
            // Where we are in the click event, $(this) refers to whatever
            // element has a class of mySelector that was clicked
            var self = $(this);
            theDiv.html('');
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "/SomeAjaxMethod",
                data: { },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Trying to access $(this) here will return undefined, as
                    // we are technically in the callback method
                    // Where our event is based on a class, there is likely more
                    // than one element on the page with the class, so it would be
                    // difficult to get the exact element again without some other code
                    self.html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("Ajax failed.")
                }
            }); // end ajax call
        }); // end on mySelector class click
</script>
```

or:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.foo').click(function () {
            var self = $(this);           // Whatever element that was clicked with foo class
            $('.bar').each(function () {
                var bar = $(this);        // Current iteration of bar element in the loop
                var baz = self;           // self is still the initial value, but $(this) is not
            }); // end bar loop
        }); // end foo click
    }); // end doc ready
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The particular example (not using JQuery) is the function closure. Referencing this in a function closure refers to the function object, not the context in which the closure was defined. Your example is one way to deal with the closure problem:

```
var that = this;
function(){
   that.something = 1;
}();
```

Another way to deal with this is with the `apply` method on the function:

```
function(arg){
   this.something = 1;
}.apply(this, argumentArray);
```

The first argument in `apply` is the "`this` argument" that "`this`" will refer too.

Answer (score 0):

One purpose of that would be to make `this` accessible to inner functions. for example:

```
function clickHandler(){
  console.log(this); // this is body
  var $self = this;
  function inner(){
    console.log(this); // this is window
    console.log($self); // this is body
  }
  inner();
}
$("body").click(clickHandler);
```

Run it in console to get a sense.